# Naming of parse string and assign value

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring

Sometimes I have this kind of code, Any advise to improve the readability
of result[0], result[1]...event the naming of result

```
var productData = "Egg 1.24 1.36";
var result = productData..Split(new char[] { ' ' });

var product = new 
{ 
Name = result[0], 
BuyPrice = result[1], 
SellPrice = result[2], 
};
```

Comment: `productDataParts` or something along that line?

Comment: You could also try to use a regular expression with named captures. That way you wouldn't have to refer to the individual parts with numbers, but names instead. Though that might be overkill for just simple string splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably overkill, but you could use an extension method based on C#
 7 and [`ValueTuple`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) to name your values right away. For instance:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static ValueTuple<string, string, string> Split(this string input, string delimiter)
    {
        var values = input.Split(new[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        return (values[0], values[1], values[2]);
    }
}
```

Then use it like that:

```
var (name, buyPrice, sellPrice) = productData.Split(" ");

Console.WriteLine(name);
```

---

**Edit:** Actually, there's a smarter way. Just write an extension method to deconstruct an array:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void Deconstruct<T>(this T[] values, out T item1, out T item2, out T item3)
    {
        item1 = values[0];
        item2 = values[1];
        item3 = values[2];
    }
}
```

Now you can just use the original `string.Split` and assign the values like the first example:

```
var (name, buyPrice, sellPrice) = productData.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: It's overkill. But still a good advise maybe I can use it in other place.

Comment: @MichaelMao I just thought of a less overkill/more reusable trick (see the edit)

Comment: Thank you. I will add the second to my project :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't how you get productData but is it possible to maybe get it as a json? That would improve the readability alot instead of splitting it and get string based on positions.

Comment: The source is a string

Answer (score 0):

Create Extension Method On The String Class Which Will Do The Split and Return an Object Of ProductData Class

```
public static YourProductClass GetProductFromString(this string CompinedString)
{
   // Do You Splitting Stuff Here and Assign The Values From String To NewProduct
   return NewProduct;
}
```

Then In You Code

```
var ProductData  = "Egg 1.24 1.36".GetProductFromString();
```